# mutual information and maximual infomation coffecient

Tags: correlation, mutual-information, partial-correlation

I am interested in calculating the strength between random variables. I found that the maximal information coefficient is one of the good methods to use and it is robust to the mutual information method. However, I need to calculate the conditional maximal information coefficient. However, based on my search, I found nothing regarding the maximal information coefficient. Is there is an R package that can do this calculation? or any published article regarding this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutual information is well known, sklearn has a good implementation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html) and in R package [entropy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/entropy.pdf).

Regarding MIC, [MICtools](https://github.com/minepy/mictools) and [minerva](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/minerva/minerva.pdf) are Python/R good implementations. See references given in MICtools repo description for further papers.

`Edit`: This is a dummy example how to compute MIC score for $x$ and $y$ conditionally given that $z=1$.

```py
from minepy import MINE
import numpy as np
mine = MINE(alpha=0.6, c=15) 

np.random.seed(42)

x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)
z = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 100)

condition_z_is_one = np.where(z > 0)[0]
mine.compute_score(x[condition_z_is_one], 
                   y[condition_z_is_one])

mic_score = mine.mic() # 0.21421355042023246
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It is appreciated. However, these packages did not count for conditional (the strength between `x` and `y` given `z`.

Comment: You could condition `x` and `y` simultaneously given set of `z` values, before passing to these implementations. Meaning we use the subset of `x` and `y` given `z` condition.

Comment: Could you please show me an example to do so and update your answer in order to accept it? As my problem is within the conditional case.

Comment: @Maryam One dummy example is added using `minepy` but using `mictools` is recommended for production.